# Why don't two variants of assembly shellcode work the same way?

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, shellcode

I've recently read Aleph One's smashing the stack for fun and profit and have been looking at "The Shellcoder's Hanbook". I was toying around with the following assembly code:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    jmp short GotoCall

shellcode:
    pop ebx
    xor eax, eax
    mov [ebx + 7], al
    mov [ebx + 8], ebx
    mov [ebx + 12], eax
    mov al, 0x0b
    lea ecx, [ebx + 8]
    lea edx, [ebx + 12]
    int 80h

    xor eax, eax
    mov al, 0x01
    int 80h

GotoCall:
    Call shellcode
    db '/bin/shJAAAAKKKK'
```

When I walk through with GDB i get a seg fault every time i try to write to:

```
mov [ebx + 7], al
```

However, when I run this i can pop a root shell without segfaulting:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    xor eax, eax
    push eax
    push 0x68732f2f
    push 0x6e69622f
    mov  ebx, esp
    push eax
    push ebx
    mov  ecx, esp
    xor  edx,edx
    mov  al, 0xb
    int  80h
```

Essentially they are doing the same thing (yes i know they aren't really, but I'm attempting to pop a root shell in both). I'm running on OpenSuse11.4 and i have stack randomization (ASLR) turned off for learning purposes. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to read: [HOWTO: Writing Good Titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/156620)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've put your `db '/bin/shJAAAAKKKK'` string into the `.text` section, which is normally not writable.

If you put it into `.data`, the crash would go away, but you'll have to get the address of the string in some other way: it would no longer immediately follow the `CALL` in `GotoCall`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I found it very helpful. I also found out that to get around the .text section being only readable (which it was) you can supply the -N option to ld when linking which will set the text and data sections to be both readable and writable.